# How to apply getPerspectiveTransform twice in 1 go/ How do I multiply the coordinates of a rectangle in a rectangle in a 2D space?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract a rectangle that is on a boardgame(called sub in the attached illustration) from a picture (called main in the attached illustration). I know the position of the rectange relative to the board, and I know the position of the board relative to the picture. My goal is to extract the rectangle from the picture with getPerspectiveTransform.

In the following image the rectangle has been replace by a single coordinate of one of the corners to make the illustration simpler.

[image: Illustration of point in a tranformed rectangle in a rectangle]

For the coordinate on the picture i expect a coordinate of something in the range of (290,190).

I tried using getPerspectiveTransform twice: once to get the board(sub) and then extract the rectangle from the resulting board(sub) image. But that leads to quality loss and is a hit on performance.

I also tried multiplying 2 matrixes with each other with the goal of getting the coordinates for the inner rectangle, but that didn't work. This calculation does not work in a 2d space. My knowledge of matrixes is almost none. My attempt:

```
main_width = 4000
mainheight = 2250

subwidth = 800
subheight = 533
# [top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left]
main  = np.float32([[386/main_width, 90/mainheight],[3441/main_width, 72/mainheight],[301/main_width, 2174/mainheight],[3540/main_width, 2163/mainheight]])
sub  = np.float32([[132/subwidth,56/subheight],[145/subwidth,79/subheight],[137/subwidth,83/subheight],[126/subwidth,59/subheight]])

innerRectangle = cv2.multiply(main,sub)
print(innerRectangle)
```

How do I extract the coordinates of the inner rectangle?

Comment: matrix multiplication isn't elementwise multiplication. check what API does what. and no, lists of points make no sense to multiply. if you had homography matrices (containing a homography or just a translation), those would make sense to multiply

Comment: you might need to learn about the geometry/math behind all this. I don't know if the "multi view geometry" is good but it's one of the "standard" books on this. the szeliski book is also popular (and you get to read the complete drafts for free) -- or check out https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html it's extremely terse and doesn't explain everything and definitely lacks sensible structure but it might be a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't get it to work with the libraries, so I tried programming it myself. I came up with the following:

```
import numpy as np

main_width = 4000
mainheight = 2250

subwidth = 990
subheight = 660

#                   0            1               2               3
#                   [top-left,   top-right,      bottom-right,   bottom-left]
main = np.float32([ [386, 90],   [3437, 72],     [3538, 2165],   [300, 2175]])
sub = np.float32([  [166, 68],   [180, 98],      [169, 103],     [156, 73]])


subTopLeftX = sub[0][0]
boardRatioWidth = subTopLeftX/subwidth#132/800
print("boardRatioWidth: \t" + str(boardRatioWidth))#.165

subTopLeftY = sub[0][1]
boardRatioHeight = subTopLeftY/subheight#58/533
print("boardRatioHeight: \t" + str(boardRatioHeight))#0.108

#              386 +          ((291-386) * 0.108)
leftsideX = main[0][0] + ((main[3][0] - main[0][0]) * boardRatioHeight)
#3444 + ((3555-3444) * 0.108)
rightsideX = main[1][0] + ((main[2][0] - main[1][0]) * (boardRatioHeight))

x = leftsideX + ((rightsideX - leftsideX) * boardRatioWidth)


#88 + ((70 - 88 ) * .165)
topsideY = main[0][1] + ((main[1][1] - main[0][1]) * boardRatioWidth)
print("topsideY: \t" + str(topsideY))
bottomsideY = main[3][1] + ((main[2][1] - main[3][1]) * (boardRatioWidth))
print("bottomsideY: \t" + str(bottomsideY))

#87 + ((2172 - 87) * .108)
y = topsideY + ((bottomsideY - topsideY) * boardRatioHeight)

print("x,y: \t" + str((x, y)))
```

This calculates 1 x,y coordinate. To calculate X, it calcaluates x at the left side of the board(leftsideX), the right side of the board(rightsideX), and multiplies the 2 based on the ratio(boardRatioWidth) of how far the coordinate is. The same is being done for Y but the other way around.